# Error: haven't defined the variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied some sample code from the Internet.

I want to copy the table on Excel into a new word document.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToWord()

    'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
    'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
    (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application 'was highlighted as error .
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Copy Range from Excel
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate

    'Create a New Document
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

    'Copy Excel Table Range
    tbl.Copy

    'Paste Table into MS Word
    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It contains at least one error, because it just runs from the beginning:

> Dim WordApp As Word.Application 'was highlighted as error .--> haven't defined the variable

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead of adding gibberish to get the question to pass concentrate to describe your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing reference.

To fix this:

> Click on Tools to select References Scroll down till you find
>   “Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library” Make sure you check the box;

Source: [Copy worksheet information to Word using VBA in Microsoft Excel](https://www.exceltip.com/applications-word-outlook-in-vba/copy-worksheet-information-to-word-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)